# Why is friction problematic on small mechanisms with multiple parts?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, friction

[This recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9c2NqlUWZfo&t=131s&ab_channel=MarkRober) concerns scaling down a nerf gun. Apparently a major problem (mentioned at 2:46) is the fact that friction "multiplies exponentially". Can someone explain more precisely why this is? (Or point to a source)

I'm new to this site. For reference, I have a math bachelor's background, but no formal mechanical engineering experience. The only exponential friction formula in mechanics I know is the Capstan Equation but that only concerns rope around an anchor. Please let me know if this question is appropriate. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more context around the 2:46 "*... friction multiplies exponentially...*"

Comment: @AJN yes. Apparently a major motivation for them to use a single (compliant) part for the 10-times-smaller nerf gun was that multiple parts result in too much friction. I’m not sure whether his use of the word “exponential” is mathematical or just for emphasis.

Comment: Stick slip, mainly. A compliant mechanism does not have cont tact frictions. so getting things moving is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what I think they mean.

Air has "friction" in the form of viscosity. An airliner can slice effortlessly  through air against the retarding force of viscosity at a speed of, say, ten meters a second.

Now we scale the system down by replacing the plane with a small bird. It has to expend significant work to move through air at ten meters a second; you can think of a bird as "swimming" through the air.

Now we scale things down again and replace the bird with a mosquito. A mosquito cannot fly through air at 10 meters a second; it is *crawling* through the air against viscosity and the best it can do is perhaps one meter a second.

Now note that as we scaled things down in size we did *not* scale down the viscosity, so the relative effects of viscosity got bigger and bigger as the objects got smaller and smaller.

The exact scaling relationship isn't strictly *exponential*; it scales more like the inverse of the scale length involved. I invite the aerodynamicists in our midst to furnish the right relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. However, I believe they're referring to the friction between different parts of the nerf gun (hence they're motivated to make it with a single part).

Comment: @benjamin wang, that sort of friction also scales in a similar way and is the reason why micromachinery rarely behaves like scaled-down macromachinery. This is especially true when you use lubricants whose viscosity is not scaled according to the scale length argument. On nanoscales, that lube acts more like glue than lubricant if unscaled!

Comment: I see. Knowing that lubricants are in the picture of multi-part products made me more convinced of the role of viscosity (which is a property of fluids)